# How to save draggable event into localstorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I try to search for saving draggable event and i found one. However it seems the problem is not solved though. It is already saved for creating new event but not when dragging it to any date.

The link to the fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/mfarouk/vcsr45q8/25/

Again i do not own this code. I try to fully understand it but somehow i have not yet learn how to store draggable event into storage. I need some guidance. In addition, this code seems to be using `backbone`.